# Is it possible to start the same activity twice and save its state?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I have an application in where I start a new screen (Activity) when an alarm goes off. This screen will have different colors and texts depending on the alarm and a notification will be sent when the user presses a button.

The problem comes up for the following scenario:

- An alarm is set for 12:00 and the screen color will be blue
- Another alarm is set for 12:02 and the screen color will be red

If the user doesn't press the button for the first alarm and it's the time for second alarm, the previous screen (blue) remains on top and the new screen (red) never shows up.

To sump up, what I want is that if the second alarm goes off and the user performed no action, the second screen (red) will appear in top of the first screen (blue) until the user presses a button. Then, the blue screen will be visible.

Can anyone think of a great approach to achieve that?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

Maybe I don't explain myself clearly. Now, I've a **single activity** that changes its appearance (color and text) depending on the alarm. This activity 'dissapears' when the user presses a button and I perform some background work. Until this point it is working fine but the problem appears when two alarms are close in time and the **same and only** activity gets called. In that case only **one** colored layout is shown.
What I expect to happen is that both colored screens are shown. I don't want to implement different activities because then I would have to create one activity for each color.

Comment: Are you sure that your Red activity is called somehow? You can add a System.out.println("Activity called"); in your Red/Blue activity. Then look at the logcat to check if "Activity called" appears twice. If not, then you probably never call the red activity.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need more activites. To achieve your goal you can simply change the background color of the layout.xml or create seperate layouts.

Comment: Yes, I change the background color depending on the screen. But what I want is for the different screens remain visible when the user **presses back button** and he/she **doesn't press the button** in the appropriate screen.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you want the blue screen to remain in the background and become visible after the second is discarded, then all you need to do is create a new intent when the second alarm is triggered to call the new screen

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, myColoredScreenActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("color", "red");
startActivity(secondIntent);
```

I believe that this new started activity (red) should lay on top the previous one (blue).

When user finishes with the red screen, just call `finish()` and the blue screen will appear.

Comment: I only have one Activity class and I'm doing what you suggest. I use putExtra() to pass the color and the text to the Activity and the different screen show up. The problem is when I need to 'overlay' one screen in top of the other, then the only screen visible is the first one.

Comment: According to this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) this should not happen. Do you call finish() anywhere in your Blue/Red activity? Can you share the code of the Red/Blue screen activity?

Comment: See my edit. What I want is some mechanism to put one screen on top of the other and not finish the first one if the user doesn't press the button. Thanks!

Comment: Add two alarms. Ask the first to call the color screen activity with the blue color as intent extra. Ask the second to call the same activity with the red color as intent extra. In the color screen activity add a System.out.println("Activity started"); Allow both alarms to trigger their attached activity. Check the logcat for the Activity Started string. Is it there two times? Or just once? If it is just once then the problem is that your second alarm doesn't call the second activity. If there are two then it calls it but for a reason unknown to me it is not placed on top in the stack.

Comment: The mechanism you ask is the one shown in my answer. Create a new intent and start the activity. Providing that you tried that and failed then what I describe in my last comment is a way to find why it fails. I believe that your problem is that the second activity never starts and not that the second activity is not placed on top.

Comment: Yes, you're totally right. The activity only gets called for the first alarm. I'm calling it from a Broadcast Receiver like this: `Intent activity = new Intent(context, MedColorActivity.class); 
            activity.putExtra("color",color);
            activity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Comment: I have never worked with Broadcast Receivers so I won't be able to help you on that. I suggest to edit this question or create a new one as the title and the content are not related to your actual problem. This way you will get some help on it.